# Tensorflow 2.0 ImageAugmentation using tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator and tf.datasets: model.fit() is running infinitely

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, data-augmentation

I am facing issue while running the fit() function in TensorFlow with augmented images(using ImageDataGenerator) passed as a dataset. The fit() function is running infinitely without stopping.

I tried it with the default code which was shared in [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).
Please find the code snippet below:

```
train_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    shear_range=0.5, 
    zoom_range=0.4, 
    rescale=1./255,
    vertical_flip=True, 
    validation_split=0.2,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True) 

test_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

ftrain_generator = train_data_generator.flow(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        shuffle=True)

ftrain_generator_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda : ftrain_generator, 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes = ([batch_size, img_rows, img_cols, num_channel],[batch_size, num_classes]))
ftest_generator = test_data_generator.flow(
        X_test,
        y_test,
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        shuffle=False)

ftest_generator_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda : ftest_generator, 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
    output_shapes = ([batch_size, img_rows, img_cols, num_channel],[batch_size, num_classes]))

ftrain_generator_ds = ftrain_generator_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ftest_generator_ds = ftest_generator_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model2.fit(ftrain_generator, epochs = num_epoch, validation_data=ftest_generator)
```

Comment: I had tried by passing  steps_per_epoch = total_no_of_train_records//batch_size . This was also mentioned in one of the stackoverflow solution, but didnt work for me.

Comment: This is a bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39277